# Hilt: Provide an instance of an interface that requires an async operation before initialization

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines, dagger-hilt

I am using firebase id token as my authorization header for http requests. To get this token from android client requires a method: `user.getIdToken(true)` which is a callback based async function.
I also have a hilt module that provides an instance of a retrofit service (interface):

Here is the service interface:

```
interface CountriesService {
    @GET("countries")
    suspend fun getCountries(): Response<CountriesResponse>
}
```

Here is the Hilt module that provides this service:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object CountriesModule {
    private const val CLOUD_RUN_BASE_URL = "https://my-base-url/"
    @Provides
    fun provideCountriesService(): CountriesService {
        return Retrofit.Builder().apply {
            baseUrl(CLOUD_RUN_BASE_URL)
            addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        }.build().create(CountriesService::class.java)

    }

}
```

Now I need to add an OkHttp inteceptor (Simply adds authorization header to all requests) to the above module like: Interceptor:

```
var client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor { chain ->

        val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        user?.getIdToken(true)?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if(task.isSuccessful){
                val token  = task.result.token
                val newRequest: Request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
                    .build()
                chain.proceed(newRequest) // return not allowed here
            } else{
                Log.d("id_token", task.exception?.message.toString())
            }
        }
        
    }.build()
```

I then pass the `client` value as a parameter to the `client()` method in the module below:

```
    @Module
    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    object CountriesModule {
        private const val CLOUD_RUN_BASE_URL = "https://my-base-url/"
        @Provides
        fun provideCountriesService(): CountriesService {
            return Retrofit.Builder().apply {
                client(client) // Newly added line
                baseUrl(CLOUD_RUN_BASE_URL)
                addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            }.build().create(CountriesService::class.java)
    
        }
    
    }.
```

The problem with the interceptor code is that one cannot return the value `chain.proceed(newRequest)` from the `addOnCompleteListener{}` block.

Is there a better way to achieve this. How can I make a callback based method return a value that is later consumed by another method?

Answer (score 0):

You have to rethink your initialization and initialize the HTTP client, as well as move all the code that relies on it, to a later phase of your application. On Android there's only a limited set of things you can do synchronously inside initialization callbacks.

Typically applications start in a phase that just shows a splash screen while they are doing initialization that requires the network.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink how you do the calls, the order of calls in particular. Probably in your interceptor you should use the cached token, but prior that, you need to do invalidation of the token. This will result your interceptor always use the latest token.

Alternatively, you can insist on firebase `Task` delivers the result blocking, you HTTP calls are always on background thread, but I wouldn't recommend.